# storing 3 values like hashmap using key and value

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to store a temporary value with it's properties like shows in the example:

```
String -> IN_LOBBY      -> true
          IN_MID_GAME   -> false
          IN_DEATHMATCH -> false
```

I made a hashmap like this but idk how to use it:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Boolean>> games = new HashMap<>();
```

The function's property is kinda like HashMap. Idk how to do it I need help.

Comment: The data structure you described would seem to match your data.  What is your actual question?

Answer (score 3):

## Just use `Map`

You can define your map using just [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html), if you do not need to access any methods specific to [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html). Doing so affords you the luxury of being able to change your choice of specific `Map` implementation without breaking calling code.

```
Map < String, Map < SportMode, Boolean > > games = new HashMap <>();
```

### Enum

From the looks of your example, the `IN_LOBBY` etc. values could be defined as an enum. An enum is appropriate when you have a limited number of possible values all known at compile-time. Using an enum provides [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety), ensures valid values, and makes your code more [self-documenting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting_code). See [tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

```java
package work.basil.example;

public enum SportMode
{
    IN_LOBBY , IN_MID_GAME , IN_DEATHMATCH
}
```

### Non-modifiable maps

If you want [non-modifiable maps](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#unmodifiable) nested, use [`Map.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#of(K,V,K,V,K,V)) found in Java 9 and later.

The `Map.of` method provides for simple literal syntax, passing a series of key-value pairs. In our case, the pairs are *string , map , string , map , …*.

```
games.put( 
    "Alice" , 
    Map.of( SportMode.IN_LOBBY , Boolean.TRUE , SportMode.IN_MID_GAME , Boolean.FALSE , SportMode.IN_DEATHMATCH , Boolean.FALSE ) 
);
games.put( "Bob" , Map.of( SportMode.IN_LOBBY , Boolean.TRUE , SportMode.IN_MID_GAME , Boolean.TRUE , SportMode.IN_DEATHMATCH , Boolean.FALSE ) );
games.put( "Carol" , Map.of( SportMode.IN_LOBBY , Boolean.TRUE , SportMode.IN_MID_GAME , Boolean.TRUE , SportMode.IN_DEATHMATCH , Boolean.TRUE ) );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "games.toString(): " + games );
```

> games.toString(): {Bob={IN_DEATHMATCH=false, IN_LOBBY=true, IN_MID_GAME=true}, Alice={IN_DEATHMATCH=false, IN_LOBBY=true, IN_MID_GAME=false}, Carol={IN_DEATHMATCH=true, IN_LOBBY=true, IN_MID_GAME=true}}

### Modifiable maps

If your nested maps must be modifiable, I would still use `Map.of` for its handy literal syntax, but feed it to the constructor of another `Map` implementation. In our case, the keys of the nested map are defined in an enum, so use `EnumMap` as it is highly-optimized for fast speed and low memory usage, and keeps its keys in enum-defined order.

```
Map < String, Map < SportMode, Boolean > > games = new HashMap <>();

games.put( 
    "Alice" , 
    new EnumMap <>( 
        Map.of( SportMode.IN_LOBBY , Boolean.TRUE , SportMode.IN_MID_GAME , Boolean.FALSE , SportMode.IN_DEATHMATCH , Boolean.FALSE ) 
    ) 
);
games.put( "Bob" , new EnumMap <>( Map.of( SportMode.IN_LOBBY , Boolean.TRUE , SportMode.IN_MID_GAME , Boolean.TRUE , SportMode.IN_DEATHMATCH , Boolean.FALSE ) ) );
games.put( "Carol" , new EnumMap <>( Map.of( SportMode.IN_LOBBY , Boolean.TRUE , SportMode.IN_MID_GAME , Boolean.TRUE , SportMode.IN_DEATHMATCH , Boolean.TRUE ) ) );
```

> games.toString(): {Bob={IN_LOBBY=true, IN_MID_GAME=true, IN_DEATHMATCH=false}, Alice={IN_LOBBY=true, IN_MID_GAME=false, IN_DEATHMATCH=false}, Carol={IN_LOBBY=true, IN_MID_GAME=true, IN_DEATHMATCH=true}}

Modify the 3rd element of the first nested map.

```
games.get( "Alice" ).replace( SportMode.IN_DEATHMATCH , Boolean.TRUE );
```

> games.toString(): {Bob={IN_LOBBY=true, IN_MID_GAME=true, IN_DEATHMATCH=false}, Alice={IN_LOBBY=true, IN_MID_GAME=false, IN_DEATHMATCH=true}, Carol={IN_LOBBY=true, IN_MID_GAME=true, IN_DEATHMATCH=true}}

### `Map` implementations

If you want to keep your `Alice`, `Bob`, and `Carol` keys in sorted order, use a `SortedMap`/[`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html) implementation such as [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html) for the outer map.

If you want to preserve the order in which keys were added to the outer map, use [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

[image: Table of Map implementations bundled with Java 11]

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
games.put("string", new HashMap<String, Boolean>());
games.get("string").add("In_lobby", true); // here we get the hashmap that corresponds do string and we add "in_lobby" to it
//... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map`'s `put` and `get` methods to add or retrieve keys and values.

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Boolean>> games = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<String, Boolean> values = new HashMap<>();
        
values.put("IN_LOBBY", true);
values.put("IN_MID_GAME", false);
values.put("IN_DEATHMATCH", false);
        
games.put("String", values);
        
System.out.println(games.get("String").get("IN_MID_GAME"));
```